# CakePHP 4 search on virtual column

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

We have a CakePHP 4.x application which contains a table of `users`. The database is MariaDB 10.7.3

Users have a first name (`fname`) and last name (`lname`). These are represented in the `users` table as 2 separate columns.

Because we want to output a user's full name in various parts of the application we return a `full_name` in our query which concatenates `fname` and `lname` with a space in between. The code looks like this:

```
// UsersController::index()
$usersQuery = $this->Users->find();

 $usersQuery->select([
    'full_name' => $usersQuery->func()->concat(['fname' => 'identifier', ' ', 'lname' => 'identifier']),
])
// ...
```

This works in terms of returning users such that we get `full_name` in the results set. We can output this data into templates.

But, we can't seem to search on that virtual column. We have the following as part of the query to perform a search:

```
$usersQuery->where([
    'OR' => [
        'fname LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
        'lname LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
     ]
]);
```

This works on `fname` and `lname` *independently*. If the user was called "John Smith" then searching for "John" would return a result. Searching for "Smith" would also return a result. But searching for the full name, "John Smith", doesn't return anything.

I tried adding:

```
'full_name LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
```

This errors with

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause'

Can I query on `full_name` and if not, how can I query a user's fullname based on a 2 column data structure as described in the first paragraph?

I did see some posts about this but they are for older versions of CakePHP and did not help with this.

Comment: Take a look at the exact query that's being generated without that `where` clause in it, to see what name is being used. It might need to include the table name, for example?

Comment: You can always use "query" (https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Configuration.md#supported-types-of-search) and custom SQL here using expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to aliases in the `WHERE` clause, at the time of processing that clause, they are not available, that's a limitation of the DBMS.

Either repeat the function call in your conditions:

```php
$usersQuery->where(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $query
) use ($searchTerm) {
    return $exp->or([
        'fname LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
        'lname LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
        $exp->like(
            $query->func()->concat([
                'fname' => 'identifier',
                ' ',
                'lname' => 'identifier'
            ]),
            "%$searchTerm%"
        ),
    ]);
});
```

or, in case applicable, use `having()` (make sure that you understand the implications of moving conditions into the `HAVING` clause before doing so, and keep in mind that the ability to refer to fields in the `HAVING` clause that are neither in the `GROUP BY` list, nor are aggregates, is a MySQL/MariaDB specific thing!):

```php
$usersQuery->having([
    'OR' => [
        'fname LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
        'lname LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
        'full_name LIKE' => "%$searchTerm%",
    ],
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**

Comment: This errors with `Call to a member function func() on null`. I tried replacing `$query` with `$usersQuery` but the same error occurs.

Comment: Fixed the example...